# Drawing a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, graphics

Hey guys i'm trying to figure out how to draw a bitmap that i have loaded onto my form.

I am using this following code to draw it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    open.ShowDialog();

    dir.Text = open.FileName.ToString();

    image = new Bitmap(dir.Text);



    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 85, 38);

 }
```

Using this nothing gets drawen, am i not using the correct draw method?

Comment: Do you get the dialog to open a file?

Comment: Wait wait wait wait...why is the `Click`-Event using `PaintEventArgs`? [`open.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) is already a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really want to paint anything yourself. Try adding a picturebox to your form, and in the button click event, simply set the image to that picturebox.

```
// In initializecomponent()
button1.Click += button1_Click;


// The click handler 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {          
      dir.Text = open.FileName.ToString();   
      image = new Bitmap(dir.Text);        
      pictureBox1.Image = image;
   }
}
```